# Is Yahoo Finance REST API legal to use?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Is Yahoo Finance API which are listed below a legal to use in application which will be distributed to public ? I could not find anything on Yahoo as of now.

Yahoo Finance API for NSE Live Quote    http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SUZLON.NS/quote?format=json&view=detail

Yahoo Finance API for NSE Live Quote    [http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SUZLON.BO/quote?format=json&view=detail](http://Yahoo%20Finance%20API%20for%20NSE%20Live%20Quote%20%09http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/SUZLON.NS/quote?format=json&view=detail)